# Approximate pi using monte carlo to certain precision

Tags: python

I understand the procedure to approximate pi using Monte Carlo. What confuses me is how to ensure that you get the desired precision (say, 4 decimal place, 3.1416) using Monte Carlo?

I tried to use a while loop ensuring the front digits are stabilized. However, the result does not converge to Pi. Could anyone help me spot the mistake in the code?

```
from random import seed
from random import random

class Solution(object):     
    def approximatePi(self):
        seed(323)
        allCount, circleCount = 0,0
        oldPi, newPi = 0, 1
        while int(oldPi * 4 * 100000) != int(newPi * 4 * 100000):
            x = random()
            y = random()
            allCount = allCount + 1
            if x * x + y * y < 1:
                circleCount = circleCount + 1
            oldPi,newPi = newPi, circleCount / allCount
            print(oldPi, newPi)
        return 4 * newPi

s = Solution()
print(s.approximatePi())
```

Comment: Converges to pi for me. First test run gave me 3.135

Comment: Yes. This code converges to 3.135. However, I multiplied it by 100000, which I believe should have a higher accuracy (3.14159), but not just 3.135.

Comment: You're not comparing your value to pi, but to the previous value. Once it stabilizes that decimal place (as in, it doesn't change after one iteration), it stops.